# GDB points to wrong current line in source with no optimization in compilation

Tags: gdb, g++

I am having this problem where GDB marker points to wrong line in the source.
So far I can tell that the marker which it is actually supposed to point to is advanced by about 3 lines.
I've looked through some similar cases and noticed that optimization levels may introduce this error, but I am using no optimization at all (didn't even specify -O).

My environment is:
Ubuntu 14.04,
Emacs 24.3.1,
GCC 4.8.2,
GDB 7.7.1

The source code I was trying to debug is:

```
#line 5 "DifferentStrings.cpp"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

#define MAX 50

using namespace std;

class DifferentStrings {
  public:

    int getDist(string A, string B) {
        assert(A.length()==B.length());
        int dist=0;
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<A.length(); i++)
            if (A[i]!=B[i])
                dist++;
        return dist;
    }

    int minimize(string A, string B) {
        int minDist=MAX;
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<B.length()-A.length(); i++) {
            string subB = B.string::substr(i,A.length());
            int thisDist = getDist(A,subB);
            if (minDist > thisDist)
                minDist = thisDist;
        }
        return A.length()-minDist;
    }
};

int main() {
    string s1("koder");
    string s2("topcoder");
    DifferentStrings ds;
    int i = ds.minimize(s1, s2);
    cout << i << endl;
    return 1;
}
// Powered by FileEdit
```

Comment: `#line 5 "DifferentStrings.cpp"` -- what do you think this is doing?

Comment: what happened to *minimal* example?

Comment: n.m: that code came from the topcoder's default setup. I retried with that line being commented out but it still didn't work.
Karoly Horvath: you mean I should've given smaller example code?

Comment: because it's caused by that `#line` directive, 3 lines (`main`) would have been enough to completely reproduce the problem.

Comment: Wow I didn't know that. When I commented it out it was still jumping to wierd positions after the return 1 so I thought that didn't have effect.

Comment: you probably didn't recompile it.

Answer (score 1):

As n.m and Karoly stated,

```
#line 5 "DifferentStrings.cpp"
```

this line causes GDB to point to wrong locations